# JSON ARRAY CREATION

Tags: arrays, delphi-xe2

Normally I don't have much issues with JSON in Delphi, but this one I am finding challenging. Perhaps I am missing some minor detail. My Json needs to look as below.
The sections "StartLocation" and "EndLocation" is what I am not sure how to code.

```
"Services": [{
        "SystemId": "AIRFLIGHT",
        "Name": "Scheduled Flight",
        "Date": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "EndDate": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "StartTime": "06h00",
        "EndTime": "13h00",
        "Agency": "Example Airline",
        "Vehicle": "EX-117",
        **"StartLocation":
            {
            "SystemId": "LHR",
            "Name": "London Heathrow"
             },
        "EndLocation": 
            {
            "SystemId": "CPT",
            "Name": "Cape Town International Airport"
            }**
      },
    {
        "SystemId": "TRANSFER",
        "Name": "Complimentary Transfer",
        "Date": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "EndDate": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "StartTime": "13h30",
        "Agency": "Example Transfers",
        **"StartLocation": {
            "SystemId": "CPT",
            "Name": "Cape Town International Airport"
        },
        "EndLocation": {
            "SystemId": "HOTEL-01",
            "Name": "Cape Town International Airport"
        }**
    },
    {
        "SystemId": "HOTEL-01",
        "Name": "Example Hotel",
        "Description": "Hotel Luxury Suite",
        "Comment": "Full Board",
        "Note": "Enjoy your 3 night stay at Example Hotel!",
        "Date": "2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "EndDate": "2018-06-04T00:00:00.000Z",
        "ReferenceCodes": ["REF-01"],
        "Adults": 1,
        "RoomName": "Luxury Suite"
       },
    {
        "SystemId": "TOUR",
        "Name": "Example Tour",
        "Description": "Full Day Example Tour",
        "Date": "2018-06-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "EndDate": "2018-06-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "Highlight": true
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the actual problem you are having with making this JSON? Can you be more specific? Please [edit] your question to show the actual code you have attempted that is not working for you the way you are expecting. Your title says you are having trouble with arrays, but the 2 fields you have indicated are not arrays at all, they are objects.

Comment: Your response mentioned: 
"but the 2 fields you have indicated are not arrays at all, they are objects."
Immediately I realized I was on the wrong track. 
With this in mind I solved the issue. Thanks for the hint.
Heres is the code I used.

StartLocObj      := TJSONObject.Create();
StartLocObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('SystemID', WComZoneGuid ) ) ;
StartLocObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('Name', GridKeyZone ) ) ;
ServiceArrObj.AddPair('StartLocation', StartLocObj); // Write the start location within
                                                    // within the ServiceArrObj

Comment: Please don't post answers inside the question itself. You are free to post an answer below